# Google API - Authenticate Users

Tags: c#, api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to implement an Google Calendar integration into my platform that would allow for certain actions to automatically ceate calerndar events and also check availability before booking requests.

My idea would be somehow a user could 'connect to google' within the platform and be taken to google to 'authorize'. This would then return some sort of credentials to be used to authorize different endpoints.

I am not quite sure where to start in terms of configuring this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Take a look at google's documentation https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference. 

In general when you are face such problems, the first thing you should do is look for the documentation of the API you are trying to integrate.

Comment: @Stefanos thanks for your comment. I understand how to use the endpoints via the documentation, however, I am struggling with how to authenticate a user via a consent screen and how that links back to provide me the auth token to access their data

Comment: Ok I think what you are after is something akin to SSO for your API where a user can log in using their Google credentials. I would point you to this 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Whos account do you want to write these events to?  A central event owned by you (do ou have google workspace), or the users own google calendar account?   Pick one and i have some sample code which may help you out.

Comment: @Stefanos Microsoft authentication is not going to get you authorization to access google calendar data.    There is a big difference between authencation and authorization.  As well as the fact that Google calendar is controlled by Google and not Microsoft.